# Resonance of Parallel RLC circuit

Tags: passive-networks

[image: Circuit]

For the circuit above, I was wondering how they derived the formula

$$\omega_0 = \sqrt{\dfrac{1}{LC} - \Big(\dfrac{R}{L}\Big)^2}$$

If anyone is able to walk me through this it would be fantastic.

Comment: To clarify the answer from Andy you need to find the frequency where the impedance is real (ie where the j part is zero). Andy's answer does this and If I were you I'd accept it.

Comment: May I further clarify? That means: The point of resonance in a lossy parallel tank circuit is NOT always the frequency where the maximum occurs but where the phase is zero (imaginary part=0). This is the DEFINITION of resonance.

Answer (score 9):

Impedance is \$\dfrac{R + j\omega L}{R + j\omega L +\frac{1}{j\omega C}}\cdot\dfrac{1}{j\omega C}\$ = \$\dfrac{R + j\omega L}{j\omega RC + j^2\omega^2 LC +1}\$ = \$\dfrac{R + j\omega L}{j\omega RC - \omega^2 LC +1}\$

If you were to multiply both the numerator and the denominator by the denominator's complex conjugate you'd get a complex equation on the top and a non-complex (real) equation on the bottom. Resonance is when the imaginary part of the new numerator equals zero so, working only on the new numerator we get: -

New Numerator = \$(R+j\omega L)\cdot (-j\omega RC - \omega^2 LC +1)\$

The imaginary part boils down to \$j(\omega L - \omega^3 L^2 C - \omega C R^2)\$

Equating this to zero we get, \$\omega L - \omega^3 L^2 C - \omega C R^2 = 0\$

Therefore, \$\omega^2 L^2 C = L - CR^2\$ and \$\omega^2 = \dfrac{1}{LC} - \dfrac{R^2}{L^2}\$

---

**EDIT section that describes other "resonances"**

It's also interesting to note that there is another resonance at play. Firstly, the "resonance" above is defined by the impedance looking into the LCR network being purely resistive - this is slightly different to the "natural" resonant frequency (also purely resistive) when R is ignored.

In this situation \$\omega = \sqrt{\dfrac{1}{LC}}\$

However, the real peak of the response (as would be seen on a spectrum analyser and not purely resistive) is found by equating the denominator to zero and solving for s where s = j\$\omega\$.

\$s^2LC +sRC +1=0\$ or

\$s^2 + s\frac{R}{L} + \frac{1}{LC} = 0\$

Using the general solution to a quadratic, we get: -

\$s= \dfrac{-\frac{R}{L} +/- \sqrt{\frac{R^2}{L^2} - \frac{4}{LC}}}{2}\$

If we use a trick of reversing the signs inside the square root part and bring the square root of -1 (j) outside we get: -

\$s = \dfrac{-\frac{R}{L} +/- j\sqrt{\frac{4}{LC} - \frac{R^2}{L^2}}}{2}\$

Now, divide thru by two and we get: -

\$s = -\frac{R}{2L} +/- j\sqrt{\frac{1}{LC} - \frac{R^2}{4L^2}}\$

As we should know the "jw" part is what we see in a bode plot so the peak magnitude of the response (not when the impedance is purely resistive) is when: -

\$\omega = \sqrt{\dfrac{1}{LC} - \dfrac{R^2}{4L^2}}\$

If you drew a pole zero diagram, the imaginary parts of the poles would be at

+/-\$\sqrt{\dfrac{1}{LC} - \dfrac{R^2}{L^2}}\$ i.e. slightly different to +/-\$\sqrt{\dfrac{1}{LC} - \dfrac{R^2}{4L^2}}\$

Comment: So resonance is simply when the impedance is purely real?

Comment: @sherrellbc no, resonance can mean several things but, in the question, I recognized the formula as the one that applies when the impedance is purely real - it's close to the peak of the response if you drew a bode plot - a fraction of a percent or so different and nobody would probably care except me LOL!