# Finding the non-zero value of ω, such that V and I will be in phase

Tags: ac, phase

Consider the impedance network connected to an AC voltage source in Fig. Q3(a).

[image]

---

i) What is the network's equivalent impedance, in terms of ω?

$$
Z_{eq}=\left(\left(Z_c+R_{10Ω}\right)||L\right)+R_{1Ω}
$$

\begin{align}
Z_c+R_{10Ω}&=10+\frac{-j}{2ω}\\
&=\frac{2ω\left(10\right)-j}{2ω}\\
&=\frac{20ω-j}{2ω}
\end{align}

\begin{align}
\left(Z_c+R_{10Ω}\right)||L&=\left(\frac{1}{jω6}+\frac{2ω}{20ω-j}\right)^{-1}\\
&=\left(\frac{20ω-j+2ω\left(jω6\right)}{\left(jω6\right)\left(20ω-j\right)}\right)^{-1}\\
&=\frac{\left(20ω-j\right)\left(jω6\right)}{20ω-j+j12ω^2}\\
\end{align}

Therefore,
$$
Z_{eq}=\frac{j120ω^2+6ω}{20ω+j\left(12ω^2-1\right)}+1
$$

---

ii) Find the non-zero value of ω, such that \$V_{in}\$ and \$I_{o}\$ will be in phase.

Since I know that \$Z_{eq}=\frac{V_{in}}{I_o}\$, if they are in phase, their cos(ωt) or sin(ωt) can cancel out each other. So \$Z_{eq}\$ do not have complex part (\$j\$).

---

**My Question**

Can I just set all the terms with \$j\$ to 0? Or, I do it in a wrong direction?

---

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Why is a resistor labelled as 10H? Also, why not put component identifiers next to the parts in the circuit then a more general solution can be found with NO confusion.

Comment: Oh it should be 10 Ohm

Answer (score 1):

Try to write your final expression in the form \$a+jb\$ by multiplying numerator and denominator with complex conjugate of denominator.

Then  equate b = 0 and solve for \$\omega\$.

**EDIT**

Multiplying numerator and denominator of 1st term with conjugate of denominator,
$$Z_{eq} =\frac{j120ω^2+6ω}{20ω+j\left(12ω^2-1\right)} \times \frac{20ω-j\left(12ω^2-1\right)}{20ω-j\left(12ω^2-1\right)} + 1$$
$$Z_{eq} =1+\frac{120ω^2+120ω^2\left(12ω^2-1\right)}{(20ω)^2+\left(12ω^2-1\right)^2} +j \frac{2400ω^3-6ω\left(12ω^2-1\right)}{(20ω)^2+\left(12ω^2-1\right)^2} $$
Equating imaginary part to zero,
$$\frac{2400ω^3-6ω\left(12ω^2-1\right)}{(20ω)^2+\left(12ω^2-1\right)^2} =0$$

Solving this will produce
\$\omega = 0,\omega = \pm j\sqrt{388},\omega=\infty\$ as the solutions.

Comment: If I set b=0, I just get Z=a, where a should be include ω, that is xω. However, I do not know what Z is, I still cannot solve ω. :c

Comment: @CasperLi I have tried to solve it for you. But I am getting \$w=\infty\$ as the only non-zero real solution.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you can ignore the 1 ohm resistor because if the other components are exactly resistive (at some value of \$\omega\$ then the addition of the 1 ohm won't change this.

So, find the impedance of the inductor, capacitor and 10 ohm resistor - that's step 1. Next, once you have the impedance you should get rid of the complex terms in the denominator by multiplying top and bottom by the denominator's complex conjugate.

This leaves you with a complex number divided by a real number.

The next trick is to equate only the imaginary part of the numerator to zero and the rest is easy - you'll find a solution for \$\omega\$ and this will be defined by L, C and R.

[Here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/116857/resonance-of-parallel-rlc-circuit) is a question that seeks to find the impedance of an L, C and R but with R in series with L. It's very close to what you are looking for.